# Is this undefined behavior or implementation defined?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

Is the following undefined or implementation-defined:

```
 int x = 0;
 printf("%d%d", ++x, x);
```

The order of evaluating arguments is unspecified, so:

- if `++x` is evaluated first, this prints `11`.
- if `x` is evaluated first, it prints `10`.

Comment: Haven't you just answered yourself? It's unspecified.

Comment: @ninjalj: by the same reasoning, I could argue that since the value at address zero is not defined in the standard, `*0` yields implementation-defined behavior.

Comment: @ninjalj: He didn't ask if it was unspecified.  He asked whether it was undefined, or implementation defined.  So no, he didn't answer himself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
printf("%d%d", ++x, x);
```

This is clearly undefined behavior in C++.

> (C++11, 1.9p15) "If a side effect on a scalar
>   object is unsequenced relative to either another side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation
>   using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined."

Same for C (emphasis mine):

> (C99, 6.5.p2) "Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression.72) **Furthermore, the prior value shall be read only to determine the value to be stored**.73"

Note that C11 has now a similar wording as in C++11:

> (C11, 6.5p2) "If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined."