# Why is "volatileQualifiedExpr + volatileQualifiedExpr" not necessarily UB in C but in C++?

Tags: c++, c, volatile, side-effects

When I today read the C Standard, it says about side effects

> Accessing a volatile object, modifying an object, modifying a file, or calling a function
>   that does any of those operations are all side effects

and the C++ Standard says

> Accessing an object designated by a volatile glvalue (3.10), modifying an object, calling a library I/O function, or calling a function that does any of those operations are all side effects

Hence because both forbid unsequenced side effects to occur on the same scalar object, C allows the following, but C++ makes it undefined behavior

```
int a = 0;
volatile int *pa = &a;

int b = *pa + *pa;
```

Am I reading the specifications correctly? And what is the reason for the discrepancy, if so?

Comment: I don't think that there is a discrepancy. For C the type of the object is the type through which the object is read, not the type an object originally has been declared. So `*pa` is an lvalue designating a `volatile` qualified object.

Comment: @JensGustedt i was assuming it refers to the concept of "effective type". Which for an object with a declared type is defined to be that declared type. So for the access "*pa", its effective type is "int" here unless I'm missing something.

Comment: "When I today read the C Standard" <- Do you usually read the C standard in the morning or at night? (173k rep, sigh...)

Comment: @H2CO3 i was [fixing wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Contributions/Litb) and wanted to get a C Standard ref :)

Comment: Ah.. fixing wiki's Comp-Sci articles on variable volatility. Cause just reading the C-standard would be weird, but doing so to update wiki-comp-sci articles is much more...normal? =P Btw. great question.

Comment: Yes, right, the effective type here is `int`. Interestingly if you would have used `volatile int *pa = calloc(sizeof *pa, 1);` the effective type would volatile.

Comment: Another thing that comes to mind is that after `int i = 0; int b = i++ + i++; // i = 2 now`, but `volatile int i = 0; int b = i++ + i++; // i = 1 now`. I believe that all operations on a `volatile` operand are pooled together across a single assignment. In C++ this is explicitly left undefined.

Comment: I do not find the words 'effective type' together in the C++ standard. Just to clarify (as it took me a while to get this just now), the `side effect` here just means that the program is *influenced* by something outside of the program flow, not necessarily that it _has_ a side effect. Reading the whole section I agree with the interpretation that this is not allowed in C++ as the program can't "wait" for the completed access from two volatile reads at the same time. (don't know about C).

Comment: @JohanLundberg, effective type is a concept in the C standard, not C++.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is an effective variation between C and C++ in this regards. Though the wording on sequencing varies the end result is the same: both result in undefined behaviour (though C seems to indicate the evaluation will suceed but with an undefined result).

In C99 (sorry, don't have C11 handy) paragraph 5.1.2.3.5 specifies:

> — At sequence points, volatile objects are stable in the sense that previous accesses are
>   complete and subsequent accesses have not yet occurred.

Combined with your quote from 5.1.2.3.2 would indicate the value of `pa` would not be in a stable state for at least one of the accesses to `pa`. This makes logical sense since the compiler would be allowed to evaluate them in any order, just once, or at the same time (if possible). It doesn't actually define what *stable* means however.

In C++11 there is explicit reference to unsequenced oeprations at 1.9.13. Then point 15 indicates such unsequenced operations on the same operand is undefined. Since *undefined behaviour* can mean anything happens it is perhaps strong than C's *unstable* behaviour. However, in both cases there is no guaranteed result of your expression.

Comment: sorry I dont understand this answer.

Comment: In short, there is no real difference in the standard between C and C++ regarding unsequenced access to volatiles. Neither guarantees an outcome for the calculation.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11657272/15416) seems to have the relevant C11 wording: (6.5p2) "If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: That's a good update. It now formalizes it is also undefined in C. So behaviour is the same in both languages now.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y : I believe the behavior has *always* been the same in both languages. The OP (Johannes) provided a couple of quotes from the standards which seem to say basically the same thing: accessing a `volatile` object from two directions at once is bad news. C11 adopts C++11's concept of sequenc *ing* (as opposed to sequence *points*), but it doesn't change the implications re UB in this case.