# Why do some Objective-C file names have a minus or plus sign in their name

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

In a library I want to add to my project, there is a file called NSString-Base64Extensions.h (with NSString-Base64Extensions.m) and one called NSString+PECrypt.h (with NSString+PECrypt.m).

What does this signify?

Comment: @jcesar [I actually had far better comments as well.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12881285/why-is-volatilequalifiedexpr-volatilequalifiedexpr-not-necessarily-ub-in-c-b#comment17440622_12881285) :P

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That is the convention for naming files, that contain *categories* for existing classes. The - and + sign are just different ways of expressing that, no difference other than style.

You can expect NSString+PECrypt.m to contain a Category that adds to the methods of  `NSString`. Likewise, NSString-Base64Extensions are Category methods on `NSString`.

Categories are a way of adding methods to an existing class in Objective-C, without subclassing, it is discussed in more detail [here](http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-categories.html).

Comment: any citation or anything? I've never seen anyone recommending using a minus sign.

Comment: No citation, but I have seen both used in the wild. + more often though.

Comment: Thank you, comment back here if you see anything ever, please.

Comment: @Yar in xcode 5, if you do File->New->File->Cocoa Touch->ObjectiveC Category it will create a filename with '+'.   Therefore it appears the Apple favors the '+' convention.  However, I think it is daft, because in both unix and windows command line the + has special meaning.

Answer (score 3):

If the programmer who wrote the files followed the Cocoa naming conventions, then these are files in which a category for a class is implemented. For example, in `NSString-Base64Extensions.h`, there should be the following category implementation:

```
@implementation NSString (Base64Extensions)

// ...

@end
```

By the way, it's not significant whether the separator between the class and the category name is a '-' or a '+' sign, it could be an underscore or whatever the developer prefers.

Answer (score 2):

They are by conventions used for files that contains category of a specific class .

```
NSString+PECrypt.h  ---> NSString : class name, PECrypt : category name
```