# '&' in a classname of objective c gets replaced by '_'

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I've written a new cocoa touch class as `Request&ApprovalViewController` and after creating found out that the class name gets replaced by `Request_ApprovalViewController` in `.h` as well as `.m` file.

`Request&ApprovalViewController.h` code

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Request_ApprovalViewController : UIViewController
@end
```

`Request&ApprovalViewController.m` code

```
#import "Request&ApprovalViewController.h"

@interface Request_ApprovalViewController ()
@end

@implementation Request_ApprovalViewController
@end
```

My question is why `&` is getting replaced by `_`?
Is it a form of writing special type of Objective-C code (like category, extension or protocol)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is how this `&` is getting replaced by `_`

A better question would be why it is replaced. The reason for it is that names of classes, variables, methods, etc. in Objective-C must be [*identifiers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identifier#In_computer_languages), i.e. they must start in a letter or an underscore, and contain only letters, digits, or underscores. `&` is not a legal character to be used in an identifier. That is why Xcode replaces it with an underscore.

Note that the name of the file is allowed to have ampersands, so Xcode keeps your file name unchanged. When you import it, use

```
#import "Request&ApprovalViewController.h"
```

Also note that [file names with `+`, a special character, are commonly used for defining *categories*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12938577/335858).

Comment: Only legal characters are allowed by xcode. You pointed it out rightly.
In addition with that, to access any instance of this class underscore contained classname to be used.
Request_ApprovalViewController *reqView = [[Request_ApprovalViewController alloc] init];

Whereas to use @class or #import directive, ampersand contained classname to be used.
#import "Request&ApprovalViewController.h"

Comment: @SoumiMaiti You are correct, Xcode does not change the file name. I edited the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Categories only use '+' special character, not others.

Answer (score 1):

You created the file with Xcode and it understands that `&` is not a valid character to have in a class name, so it changed it to a sensible stand in character such that it will be able to compile the code.

Answer (score 1):

Ampersand is a reserved symbol due to Objective-Cs relationship with C, where it is used for taking an address of a variable.

Comment: It's not reserved, it just cannot be used in an identifier.  It's also used for more than taking the address of a variable.